# Censor images and tables

Tags: graphics, pdf, drm

My publication requires a public and non-public version. I have several figures and tables that I'd like to censor by placing a big colored block on top of it. One page suggested using `\colorbox`. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for pdf files.

All of the images and tables are simple `\includegraphics`.

Anyone have a clue?

Update @doncherry, this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\colorbox{black}{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{\string"Image".pdf}}
\caption{Google Adwords - BoI}
\end{figure}
```

produces:

[image: Colorboxed image]

Comment: For the nonpublic version say `\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}`

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried with `\colorbox` that didn't work? @egreg's suggestion works but one should note that that will blacken _all_ images.

Comment: @doncherry You can as well put `\includegraphics[draft]{mypicture.png}`, but it'll mean that you have to change the code manually.

Comment: I have upgraded the censor package (as of 2/19/13) to be able to redact things like figures and tables (anything stored in a LaTeX box).  The upgrade was uploaded to CTAN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the option `decodearray` to produce a black image with a suitable switch. The image below shows the uncensored and censored image respectively.

[image]

The MWE is shown below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}
\newif\ifcensored
\begin{document}
\centering
\ifcensored
    \includegraphics[decodearray=
                                 0.0 0.0
                                 0.0 0.0 
                                 0.0 0.0, width=5cm]{amato.jpg}%
\captionof{figure}{censored image}
\else
   \includegraphics[width=5cm]{amato.jpg}% image with RGB colors
   \captionof{figure}{uncensored}
\fi
\includegraphics[decodearray=
                                 0.0 0.0
                                 0.0 0.0 
                                 0.0 0.0, width=5cm]{amato.jpg}%
\captionof{figure}{censored image}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{amato.jpg}% image with RGB colors
\captionof{figure}{uncensored}
\end{document}
```

The code works well with `.png` as well as `.jpg` images. Details for `decodearray` can be found in the [PDF Reference Manual](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/PDFReference.pdf). As a matter of interest if the values of the pairs have values other than zero one can manipulate the color channels, producing a reddish image for example.

Of course you will need to incorporate a suitable command to replace `\includegraphics`. One such approach is to define:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\cimage}[3][]{
\ifcensored
    \includegraphics[decodearray=
                                 0.0 0.0
                                 0.0 0.0 
                                 0.0 0.0, width=5cm]{#2}%
\captionof{figure}{#3(censored image)}
\else
   \includegraphics[width=5cm]{#2}% image with RGB colors
   \captionof{figure}{#3}
\fi
}
```

To censor the images you type,

```
\censoredtrue
\cimage{amato.jpg}{A caption for your figure}
```

Note that the image data is still included in the pdf and can possibly be extracted, so use with caution or in cases where paper copies only will be circulated.

Comment: Does this work with non-jpeg images?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Yes it does.

Comment: Looks good! Two questions (that you perhaps could answer within your answer): What is `decodearray` actually intended for? Doing this for every image in a paper might be pretty tedious -- can this be put in a macro, similar to @tohecz's solution? And a third question actually: Is the typo in `\ifcencored` intentional?

Comment: @doncherry Thanks! Will put some more info in the morning and fix the typo!

Comment: @doncherry I noticed the typo as well and thought like "maybe `\ifcensored` is some LaTeX internal?" :)

Comment: @tohecz ... more like an internal bug in my brain:)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate response! Tried it and it definitely works. However; for now I'll probably just go with the [draft] solution of @tohecz. It might be less elaborate but the quick fix is good enough for now!

Comment: Even though `decodearray` is an underexploited feature, which can be really useful (the explanation was useful to me for something else), this is completely inappropriate for censoring: the whole image data is still included in the pdf, just not shown by default.  It is important to note this in the answer.  As it stands, I'm tempted to downvote.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Thanks for the note, where are you using the feature? I have added a note as a caveat.

Comment: Wedding invitations which should include grayscale pictured transformed (through a `decodearray`) to shades of another color (to match with the text).  At the end of the day, we decided to go for gray anyways, but here is [my question on that topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/150225/2707)

Answer (score 5):

### Variant One - `\includegraphics` and `\DRMincludegraphics`

The following code embeds the egreg's idea in a more sophisticated way. It introduces new command `\DRMincludegraphics`. If you set `\iftrue` at the beggining, it will add `draft` option to the command which hides the graphics. If you set `\iffalse`, it behaves like the ordinary `\includegraphics`. You have to put the code after you load `graphicx` package.

```
\iftrue
  \makeatletter
  \def\@DRMincludegraphics[#1]{\includegraphics[#1,draft]}
  \def\DRMincludegraphics{\@ifnextchar[%
    \@DRMincludegraphics%
    {\includegraphics[draft]}%
  }
  \makeatother
\else
  \let\DRMincludegraphics\includegraphics
\fi
```

---

### Variant Two - `\alwaysincludegraphics` and `\includegraphics`

Works the same way as Variant One, just with the difference that the default command is the one that gets hidden.

```
\iftrue
  \let\alwaysincludegraphics\includegraphics
  \makeatletter
  \def\bracket@includegraphics[#1]{\alwaysincludegraphics[#1,draft]}
  \def\includegraphics{\@ifnextchar[%
    \bracket@includegraphics%
    {\alwaysincludegraphics[draft]}%
  }
  \makeatother
\else
  \let\alwaysincludegraphics\includegraphics
\fi
```

Comment: I guess that's kind of what I was just working on. Now, assuming you want to censor most of the images, but a few not (say, a logo on the title page), could you adapt this so that images included via the normal `\includegraphics` are censored, but images included via e.g. `\alwaysincludegraphics` are not censored?

Comment: I was thinking about that variant as well, gimme a minute.

Answer (score 5):

If all images you include with `\includegraphics` are to be censored, then saying

```
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
```

will use the real bounding box for the images, but will print instead a box with the file name.

If not all the images are to be censored, I suggest to use for those a different command:

```
\newcommand{\cincludegraphics}[2][]{%
   \includegraphics[draft,#1]{#2}}
%\let\cincludegraphics\includegraphics % Uncomment for "private version"
```

Use `\cincludegraphics` just like `\includegraphics`. For the nonpublic version it's sufficient to uncomment the following line.

This doesn't support `\cincludegraphics*`, but for that it's equivalent to specify the `clip` option.

If you also want to hide the file name, you can add (after having loaded `graphicx`)

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}{\rlap}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother
```

In case you prefer to replace the file name with a word, you can say instead

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\def\CENSORED@IMAGE#1{{\footnotesize Censored}}
\patchcmd{\Gin@setfile}{\rlap}{\CENSORED@IMAGE}{}{}
\makeatother
```